# Login Button to TabBarController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

So I have a login of `UIViewController`. I want when after user give user and pass then click button, the view will switch to main page which is `UITabBarController`

Anyone know how to do that programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you login successully, just change the root view controller of the windows to your tabbarController

```
func didLoginSuccess() {
    // let yourTabbarController = .....
    // Dont forget to edit this, put your animation while the view change
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = yourTabbarController 
}
```

Comment: This answer is not wrong to get down vote.

Comment: Yes! This actually the answer that I need! Thank you!

Comment: @TheTiger : thankyou :)

Comment: @RaditiaMadya you're welcome